# Can I open a usercontrol from another usercontrol in WPF?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a MainWindow in a WPF application who loads 3 usercontrols. 
I want if it's possible to call a usercontrol from another with a button.
Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to add a user control to a user control graphically? Or do you want to access the other user controls from a user control?

Comment: Thanks for the responce.I want with a button to make the second usercontrol visible.

Comment: Are the user controls placed on top of eachother so that the active usercontrol needs to be hidden. Or is it just a matter of making it visible when a button is clicked?

Comment: The second my friend, making it visible when a button clicked

Comment: dont you just want something like this `Control2.Visibility = Collapsed` in the click event of the button? Am I missing

Comment: The button is in the first usercontrol. I did that but it gives an error Object reference..... etc

Comment: Raise the usercontrol's click event when the button is clicked. Attatch to it in your MainWindow and use it to change your visibility accordingly.